# How do I run a generic file in Android?

Tags: java, android, file

I'm working on a file explorer for Android in Android studio. I need to run or open with the corresponding app any file the user clicks (like any other file explorer), but I don't know what command to use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, the closest thing to "run" would be to call `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. You would need to use something like `MimeTypeMap` to help Android determine the MIME type given the file extension, adding that MIME type to the `Intent`.